# mongooose $text search if null

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a query like so.

```
Resource.find({
            isResource:true,
            $text: {$search: req.query.search}
        }).lean().exec(function(err, resources){
        if(err){
            next(err);
            return;
        }else{
            res.send(resources);
        }
    });
```

Sometimes a user wont want to enter a search query and thus would just return all resources that are true. However, if I provide a null value to the $search property, I get an error. If I provide an empty string, it returns no items since it's searching with an empty string.

Is there a conditional way for $search to handle null values without having to add another query omitting the $text field when the req.query.search is empty or null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but it's simple to omit that term in your query by programmatically assembling your query:

```
let query = { isResource: true };
if (req.query.search) {
    query.$text = {$search: req.query.search};
}
Resource.find(query).lean().exec(function(err, resources){
    if(err){
        next(err);
        return;
    }else{
        res.send(resources);
    }
});
```

Comment: how about in aggregate section sir? i tried ur answer but still get empty